# Show label over text in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-formatting, uuid

I'm using uuids and I want to be able to display the name of the object linked to the uuid without looking at a lookup table. for example `df953d9c-234f-4ac2-af5e-f0490b223e71` is linked to wood. is there a way of displaying wood whenever i hover over something containing the uuid?

Comment: Notepad++ is not programmable.

Comment: Short answer: I'm afraid NO.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Notepad++ can only do what it is programmed to do and what you are asking for is not something it is programmed to do.